# Need CSS/HTML help fixing navigation in IE

Tags: html, css, wordpress, internet-explorer, navigation

Just launched a new Wordpress site, and for some reason that I can't figure out, the navigation is pushed way to the right and then rolls onto the next line, but only in IE.

I only have access to IE 11 on Windows 7, so I can't be sure if it's doing the same thing in other versions.  But it looks fine in Chrome, Safari and FireFox on both Windows and Mac.  The theme is highly responsive and it also works fine on my iPhone.

Anyway, here's the site:

http://www.all-about-wolves.com

And here's the main .css file:

http://www.all-about-wolves.com/wp-content/themes/TheHunter/style.css

Any ideas?  Virtual beer for whoever can point to a solution!!!

Comment: Sorry but you need to isolate the problem and present it here, with different things you tried. You can't just post a link to the site and its CSS file

Comment: Also, you shouldn't put links to external sites in your question. That kind of activity is frowned upon on this site.

Comment: Open the developer tools and try enabling/disabling individual CSS properties using the HTML inspector.

Comment: Just had a look for you, but the IE inspector is awful. 
What seems to be the issue is another element is pushing down into the nav, I suspect a div within the logo, and then forcing the nav list to the right. 

Try adding a margin-top to the nav bar, so it has a bit of backbone. It's usually a 1px difference with this sort of stuff. 
That's the direction you should be going in. Good luck buddy. If it's not solved I'll have another look when I get home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that in IE the menu starts where the site logo ends.
To fix this, edit your css and make sure the 'clearfix' will works properly on all browsers.

```
.clearfix {
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Bam!  Great catch.  I had not made the connection that the nav started where the logo ended.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear your float left (or both) on the `<div class="clearfix">` that wraps your menu.

Comment: also the correct answer, but I can only mark one of them. Thank you.